# AngularJs и asp.net mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос. Я в последнее время вижу, что angular js стал очень популярен и мне вздумалось заняться его изучением. Но основная моя сфера деятельности это asp.net mvc. Я бегло посмотрел возможности angular и пришёл к выводу что они во многом дублируются возможностями asp.net mvc. Например сам паттерн mvc который используется  в angular уже реализован в asp.net mvc. Или скажем биндинг модели к элементам страницы - это же прекрасно можно сделать с помощью Razor. У меня возникает дилетантский вопрос а насколько вообще оправдано использование angular js в приложениях asp.net mvc? Какие важные преимущества этот фреймворк дает для asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular предназначен для построения этой архитектуры на стороне клиента.
Это сильно облегчает разработку отзывчивых приложений и значительно уменьшает нагрузку на сервер, с которого снимается обязанность рендеринга контента и постоянной передачи избыточных данных.

Вы можете использовать Angular в связке ASP.NET.
В таком случае, обычно, Angular используется для написания всей UI части, а Web API 2 выступает в качестве сервиса, который отвечает только за бизнес-логику и предоставление данных.

Есть много других фрэймворков и библиотек, которые позволяют делать похожие вещи.
Ember, Angular, Backbone, Knockout, React - разные способы достижения одних целей - отзывчивости приложения и стройной архитектуры UI.